# Why does createHmac of NodeJS' crypto module create the wrong SHA512 HMAC?

Tags: node.js, typescript, hmac

I'm currently struggling with a problem that gets me crazy..

It's about a client - server setup where the client signs a message sent to the server, using a nonce that was provided by the server before hand.
The signing itself is not the problem since the signature created from the client is correct (I checked it with an external SHA512 HMAC tool). However, in order to verify the signature the server has to also calculate the signature and this fails for some reason.

I'm using Typescript on a NodeJS server with the crypto module.

This is my code (Server side):

```
const secret = this.session.logInRequest.nonce;
const hmac: string = createHmac('sha512', secret)
            .update(payload)
            .digest('base64');
```

For the payload `t0pS3cr3t` (let's assume this is a users password) and the nonce (used as the secret) `X2Zs56qqV0Q+acMF3rnECQ==` this is the signature calculated by the server:
`9glN9glPnQSSOG3pFN6KHBWcRmk/WpFA9YiXUjamG91QgiV/az7zOyAc1WV0B4lwNiXeASrQP6zbXdTd0D1lQw==`
And this is the (correct) signature provided by the client:
`T/c8WbEdBz4Tvm9IvI764HP1bwuFbvNS2ps4HLOThyeJptbbcy/vt0x3cZ+pM9CE5YSJXJ0WCEuFWdGlSQN4bA==`

Any explanation what I'm doing wrong here would really be appreciated!

Comment: This sort of problem usually means that either the payload or the secret is wrong in some way, e.g. encoded in a different way that you'd intended.

Comment: yeah.. you're totally right. I just realized that the client is sending the wrong payload which is not matching the signature it calculated with the correct payload before hand.
It's 02:30am here.. I think I better go to bed 